# Using private GitHub package with ShinyApps.io

Tags: r, github, shinyapps

I am having trouble making my ShinyApps.io account install a private GitHub dependency:

First, on ShinyApps.io, I have authorized private repository access:

[image: private access]

Second, in my package that I am deploying, I have added the private dependency as a `Remotes` package in the `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Remotes:
    myOrg/myDependency
```

Third, ShinyApps.io is and authorized application on GitHub under the repository settings.

However, when I attempt to manually deploy, ShinyApps is unable to find `myDependency`. I get an error that states:

```
Warning: Unable to determine the repository for package myDependency
```

What else do I need to check to be sure ShinyApps.io can reach and use my dependency

Answer (score 1):

Going to focusing on getting this working and not necessarily the most elegant or right solution here.

1. Revoke access to shinyapps at https://github.com/settings/applications and re-establish the connection from shinyapps (*make sure to include the organizational grant* if your dependency repo is owned by an org and not you personally).

---

2. Make the dependency install from github a `source` script as part of the beginning of your app launch?

Something like:

`app.r`

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

source(private_dependency.R)

*app code here*
```

`private_dependency.R`

```
library(devtools)
install_github("hadley/private", auth_token = "abc")
```

Where auth_token is a value you generated at: https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comments on auth_token storage from the docs:

> To install from a private repo, use auth_token with a token
> from https://github.com/settings/tokens. You only need the
> repo scope. Best practice is to save your PAT in env var called
> GITHUB_PAT.

[Reference](http://devtools.r-lib.org/reference/install_github)

---

3. Support ticket? It just doesn't seem to me like anything about the github process here is verbose enough to know what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

update 06.2023: I needed for some reasons to change the default location, the log in shinyapps.io said:

Warning in i.p(...)  'lib = "/opt/R/4.2.2/lib/R/library"' is not writable

So I added in app.R (before source("./private_dependency.R") code like this (put in proper 'myApp'):

```
`# NOTE log entry: Working directory: /srv/connect/apps/<myApp>
 # -> install here since default is not writable
 temp_path <- c("/srv/connect/apps/<myApp>", .libPaths())
 .libPaths(temp_path)`
```